# google chart form jsonp but windows is wirng

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am drawing a google chart from datafun.com with jsonp. However, I cant get it to print the data in a time window like: "now and 1 day back". 
I have tried:

```
data: {'gt' : {'timestamp' : 'now - 24hours'}},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
```

and  `data: {'gt' : {'timestamp' : 'now - 10'}},`

and  `data: {'gt': {'timestamp' : 'now - 24hours'}},`

but results are less than satisfying (wrong).

who has an answer.

Here is the code of one graph:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart3);
 function drawChart3() {

        var public_key = 'yA0EjKV3owhKNx1NlN3w';

        // JSONP request
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
         // data: {page: 1},
          data: {'gt': {'timestamp' : 'now - 24hours'}},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).done(function (results) {

              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

              data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
              data.addColumn('number', 'Humid');

              $.each(results, function (i, row) {
                data.addRow([
                  (new Date(row.timestamp)),
                  parseFloat(row.humidity)
             ]);
                            }); // each row
          var options = {title:'Humidity Outside',
                       width:450,
                       height:300};
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart3').get(0));
                  chart.draw(data, options); // draw data
          }); // results

      } // jsondata

<div id="chart3" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" ></div>
```

also see https://www.hanscees.com/photon/charts-data-sparkfun.html (wait 30sec its slow )

Comment: can nobody help? how do you write a time that is "from yesterday until just now"?

Comment: well at least this is a beginning: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes